# Proving $\sqrt{a^2+c^2}+\sqrt{b^2+d^2}\ge \:\sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^2+\left(c+d\right)^2}$

Tags: inequality

The inequality:

$$\sqrt{a^2+c^2}+\sqrt{b^2+d^2}\ge \:\sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^2+\left(c+d\right)^2}$$

But can someone help me with a nice elegant solution. This is an olympiad question I was trying to solve, but couldn't manage an elegant solution.

Comment: Use AM-GM, $a^2d^2+b^2c^2\ge2abcd$. Keep adding terms and taking square roots.

Comment: Square, simplify, square, simplify.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 8):

Since squaring is monotonic, this is equivalent to
$$
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 2\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+d^2} \ge a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 + 2(ab + cd)
$$
which is in turn equivalent to
$$
ab + cd \le \sqrt{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+d^2},
$$
the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Putting it in vector form is even more elegant. For $\mathbf{a} = (a,c)$ and $\mathbf{b} = (b,d)$, this is
$$
|\mathbf{a}| + |\mathbf{b}| \ge |\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}|,
$$
the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{a^2+c^2}+\sqrt{b^2+d^2}\ge \:\sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^2+\left(c+d\right)^2} \\ 
\left( \sqrt{a^2+c^2}+\sqrt{b^2+d^2} \right)^2 \ge \: \left( \sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^2+\left(c+d\right)^2} \right)^2 \\ a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2+2\left( \sqrt{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+d^2} \right) \ge \: \left(a+b\right)^2+\left(c+d\right)^2 \\ 
a^2+c^2+b^2+d^2+2\left( \sqrt{(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)} \right) \ge \: a^2+2ab+b^2+c^2+2cd+d^2 \\ 2\left( \sqrt{(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)} \right) \ge \: 2ab+2cd \: \: \: \text{(subtract} \: a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \: \text{from both sides)} \\ \sqrt{(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)} \ge \: ab+cd \: \: \text{(divide both sides by 2)} \\ (a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2) \ge \: (ab+cd)^2 \\ a^2b^2+a^2d^2+c^2b^2+c^2d^2 \ge \: a^2b^2+2abcd+c^2d^2 \\ a^2d^2+c^2b^2 \ge \: 2abcd \: \: \text{(subtract } \: a^2b^2+c^2d^2 \: \text{from both sides)} \\ a^2d^2+c^2b^2 \ge \: 2abcd$$